# Segmenting only Face in an Image in EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, image-segmentation

I am hoping to achieve something similar to what is shown in this [video](https://youtu.be/Mp1_TM_IRdA).

I have been able to detect face in image, and then cropping a rectangle containing the face using haar cascade classifier. But, because faces are not completely rectangle, some of the background are still shown in the cropped image.

I am trying to achieve what was shown in the video so I can remove the background part of the cropped image.

Is there any way to do it using Emgucv?

Thank you!